# Verbose mode in Django template tags

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Is there any possibility to write into generated view verbose informations about template generation in debug mode? For example it could generate such output:

base.html:

```
<html>
<body>
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

page.html:

```
{% extend "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
Foo
{% include "inner.html" %}
Bar
{% endblock %}
```

Into such form:

```
<html>
<body>
<!-- block content -->
<!-- from "page.html" -->
Foo
<!-- include "inner.html" -->
Bar
<!-- endblock content -->
</body>
</html>
```

Why? Because sometimes exploring some larger dependencies are very hard just by IDE. Or maybe you know some good tool for easier navigation (generating graphs etc.)? Of course this informations should be generated only in debug mode. In production they should disappear.

Comment: Good question! You might see if [`django-debug-toolbar`](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar) or  [`django-template-repl`](https://github.com/codysoyland/django-template-repl) is helpful.

Comment: For me `django-template-repl` is totaly useless, because I need to enter whole tree of files into it and if I would know answer to which file is bad I would have my answer without it. I created this question because of magic templatetags in code that now I maintain, which are using magic depending on inserted model (templates as list: `("{app_label}/{model}/{template}.html", "{template}.html")`) and output are too similar to distinct template using its content. `django-debug-toolbar` is close, but not enough, now I'm using it.

Comment: magic is evil. have you thought of a little sed script to add the html comment after every block/include and befor every endblock ?

Comment: Assuming this strictly for development/debugging purposes, you could monkeypatch/instrument the Django template system to add a HTML comment near every `{% block ... %}`/`{% endblock %}` at either the parse or pre-parse stage...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to achieve this using middlware. I was having a similar issue a while back keeping track of templates and the views calling them so I wrote a middleware snippet that added a comment block to the top of the html response. It doesn't quite do what you're asking but you might be able to adapt it.

```
COMMENT_BLOCK = """
<!--
[ url      ] >> http://%(host)s%(path)s
[ referer  ] >> %(referer)s
[ module   ] >> %(module)s
[ function ] >> %(function)s, line %(line)s
[ args     ] >> args=%(args)s, kwargs=%(kwargs)s, defaults=%(defaults)s
[ template ] >> %(template)s
-->

"""

# Add any additional template types you wish to add the comment block to.
MIMETYPES = (
    "text/html",
    "text/xml",
)


class HtmlTemplateFinder:

    def __init__(self):
        self.host = None
        self.referer = None
        self.path = None
        self.module = None
        self.function = None
        self.line = None
        self.args = None
        self.kwargs = None
        self.defaults = None
        self.template = None
        self.valid_template = False

    def _populate_comment_block(self):
        return COMMENT_BLOCK % {
                                'host': self.host,
                                'referer': self.referer,
                                'path': self.path,
                                'module': self.module,
                                'function': self.function,
                                'line': self.line,
                                'args': self.args,
                                'kwargs': self.kwargs,
                                'defaults': self.defaults,
                                'template': self.template,
                               }

    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        self.host = request.META.get('HTTP_HOST', None)
        self.referer = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', None)
        self.path = request.path
        self.module = view_func.func_code.co_filename
        self.function = ('.').join((view_func.__module__, view_func.func_name))
        self.line = view_func.func_code.co_firstlineno
        self.args = view_args
        self.kwargs = view_kwargs
        self.defaults = view_func.func_defaults
        return None

    def process_template_response(self, request, response):
        from mimetypes import guess_type
        # Use this rather than response.template_name, this always returns str
        self.template = response.resolve_template(response.template_name).name
        self.valid_template = guess_type(self.template)[0] in MIMETYPES
        return response

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        from <your app> import settings
        if settings.DEBUG:
            if self.valid_template:
                block = self._populate_comment_block()
                response.content = "%s%s" % (block, response.content)
        return response
```